# How to get information from divs to another div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello guys please I have a question.
In my code I have two div with the same Parent and children class but with different info and I also have another separate div which I want the info to appear(that is the info (paragraphs) inside of the parent with class of post) if I click on any of the button on the two div. Eg if I click first div  button I want the info from it and if I click second div button I also want the info to show by overriding the current info in the separate div. Please help me you can use jquery or js

```
<div class="post">
       <p class="postText">Hello how are you</p>
       <p class="posts">My Info</p>
       <button>getInfo</button>
   </div>



     <div class="post">
       <p class="postText">Hello how are you doing today</p>
       <p class="posts">My Information</p>
       <button>getInfos</button>
   </div>

<div class="separate_div_to_appear"></div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "I want the info from it" - what part do you consider to be the "info"?

Comment: Please make an attempt yourself before posting questions on Stack Overflow, thank you

Comment: @Bright Were any of the below answers helpful to you? If so, please select a "correct" answer *(by clicking the checkmark beside an answer)* to close the question, or provide an answer yourself and choose that as the correct answer. Otherwise, please add comments below one of the answers or edit your original question to add more detail so that additional answers can be provided. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting you well, this might be the answer. Otherwise I would suggest to better define your requirements.

```
$(".postText").click(function(s){
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(".separate_div_to_appear").text(text);
});
```

Comment: It you are getting the text out of one element, and you are using JQuery, then use the `.text()` method for both getting and setting the text. Not `.html()`.

Answer (score 0):

Detect the button click by binding a `.click()` method to this selector:

```
$('.post button')
```

In the event handler, `$(this)` will be the button that was clicked. So, starting from there, you need to travel up the DOM elements to find the `closest()` element with a class of `post`. Grab all the html in there - you will get the `<p>` elements and the `<button>` element. Note that `.html()` with nothing inside it is a ***getter.***

Now, identify the target div using the selector `$('.separate_div_to_appear')`, and again use `.html()` to insert the copied HTML elements. Note that `.html()` with stuff inside is a ***setter.***

Final step: You don't want the `button` element copied around, so delete it from the target div.

*Of course, my code could have been more elegant and identify what to copy and what not to copy, but you can figure that part out. I wanted this example/demo to be very simple, very short, so you just see how it's done.*

```js
$(function(){
  $('.post button').click(function(){
    let pp = $(this).closest('.post').html();
    $('.separate_div_to_appear').html(pp);
    $('.separate_div_to_appear').find('button').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.separate_div_to_appear{height:100px;margin-top:20px;background:wheat;padding:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="post">
      <p class="postText">Hello how are you</p>
      <p class="posts">My Info</p>
      <button>getInfo</button>
   </div>



   <div class="post">
      <p class="postText">Hello how are you doing today</p>
      <p class="posts">My Information</p>
      <button>getInfos</button>
   </div>

<div class="separate_div_to_appear"></div>
```